# Excel VBA incrementing columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to combine multiple columns of varying lengths into 1 column on another sheet to allow for vlookups off this column.

I am able to increment down through the first column easily, but I am having trouble moving on to the next column.

Below is the code that I was working with. I am trying to use the cells identification to increment the column number but I am getting an application define or object define error 1004.

```
Sub TestTwo()
   Sheets("Transposed").Activate
   Dim row As Double

   row = 3

  'Do Until Sheets("Transposed").Range("B" & row).Value = ""
   Do Until Sheets("Transposed").Range(Cells(row, "B")).Value = ""

  Sheets("OneList").Range("B" & row - 1).Value = Sheets("Transposed").Range("B" & row).Value
row = row + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

The first do until line is commented out because I am trying to get the cells identifier to work before trying to increment.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Range() is looking for either an address or a range of cells.  Use the Cells() by itself:

```
Do Until Sheets("Transposed").Cells(row, "B").Value = ""
```

Range does not like a single Cells() reference.

Comment: Thank you Scott. It was so frustrating because I knew it was something simple but couldn't figure out how to address the issue.  Everything is working as intended now!

Answer (score 2):

Scott is exactly correct (+1). But, I would approach this problem a bit differently than you with `For` loops. That way you can be more precise, and keep track of what everything does if you need to scale up

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineColumns()
    Dim sourceColumns As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim combinedRow As Long
    combinedRow = 1
    Dim sourceRows As Long

    For sourceColumns = 2 To 4 'B, C, D or whatever your range is
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceColumns).End(xlUp).Row
        For sourceRows = 1 To lastRow
            Sheet2.Cells(combinedRow, 1) = Cells(sourceRows, sourceColumns)
            combinedRow = combinedRow + 1
        Next
     Next sourceColumns
End Sub
```